# approximations of continuous functions by differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a continuous function and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x)=0$. Prove that exists two functions $g,h \colon (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ of class $C^1$ such that $g\le f\le h$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} h(x)=0$.

Comment: Did you place any thoughts into this? People are much more likely to help you if you show that you have already done something with the problem.

Comment: The limit lets you bound your function with constant functions around $0$. To make them tend to $0$, you just have to take those constants smaller and smaller as you get closer to $0$. And then, you just need to see how you can join two horizontal lines by a $C^1$ curve which isn't that hard (you could think of using a scaled and translated $\sin$).

Comment: how can I join two horizontal lines by $C^1$ curve?

Comment: I've just given you additional hints on that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Divide $(0, \infty)$ into overlapping intervals, for example:
$$\mathbb J=\left\{\left(\frac{1}{n+1.1},\frac{1}{n-0.1}\right) \right\} \cup \left\{(n-0.1, n+1.1) \right\}$$

For each such interval you can find a *positive* value (why?) that bounds the function $f$ on that interval (from above for $h$ and from below for $g$). You can think of it as an multivalued (on overlapping segments) function, "constant" on each interval from $\mathbb J$. To finish, you need to inductively change multivalued segments into smooth connections of the neighbouring intervals - for example using $\sin$ as proposed in the comments.

**EDIT.** Hint on joining.

You can join the horizontal line $[-3,-\pi/2]$ at the $-1$ level with the horizontal line $[\pi/2,3]$ at the $1$ level with $\sin$, right? Then find out how to join the same lines at levels $-5$ and $5$ respectively, and then $0$ and $10$ respectively. Then you are ready to think, how to join two horizontal lines over $[-10,-3\pi]$ and $[3\pi, 20]$. Finally consider the most general case.